# Show uniqueness in Hilbert-space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In this theorem, I need to **prove that $z_0$ is unique**:

> Let $K$ be a proper closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space, and $x\in
> K^c$. Then there exists a unique $z_0 \in K^{\perp}$ such that
>   $\|z_0\|=1$ and
>
> $\rho(x,K)=\inf\{\|x-y\| : y \in K\}=\langle x,z_0 \rangle$.

There is an earlier theorem that is tied to this one, and which I can use:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $K$ a closed linear subspace of $H$. For each
>   $x \in H$ there is a unique point $y_0\in K$ such that:
>
> $\|x-y_0\|=\rho(x,K)$ where $\rho(x,K)=\inf\{\|x-y\|: y \in K\}$.
>   Furthermore, the point $y_0$ is determined by the conditions:
>
> $y_0 \in K$ and $\langle x-y_0,y \rangle = 0$ for all $y \in K$.

When solving this exercise, I have not yet proved that for a closed subspace of a hilbert space, we have the decomposition of any vector, I am supposed to prove that later with this theorem, so **I can not use that we can decompose $x$ in a unique vector in $K$ and another in its complement.**

My attempt:

Assume that $z_0$ is not unique, then there is another vector $z_1\in K, \|z_1\|=1$, and $\|x-y_0\|=\langle x,z_0 \rangle = \langle x,z_1\rangle$.

We must also have then that $\langle x,z_0-z_1 \rangle=0$, and since $K^\perp$ is a closed subspace we have that $z_0-z_1$ is in $K^\perp$. So I get that $\langle x-y_0,z_0-z_1 \rangle = 0$. But I do not get that this leads to anything.

If I can show that $\langle z_0-z_1,z_0-z_1 \rangle = 0$, I will be done.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You are over thinking it.

Assume $z_0\in K^\perp$ have the said properties. Let $d = \|x - y_0\| = \rho(x, K) = \langle x,z_0 \rangle$.
Notice that
$$ x = (x - d z_0) + d z_0, $$
which is obviously the orthogonal decomposition of $x$:
$$ \langle x - d z_0, d z_0 \rangle = d\langle x, z_0 \rangle - d^2 \|z_0\|^2 = d^2 - d^2 = 0. $$
That is, for every $y\in K$ we have
\begin{align} 
\| x - y \|^2 &= \| x - dz_0 + dz_0 - y \|^2 \\
&= \| dz_0 - (y - (x - dz_0)) \|^2 = d^2 \|z_0\|^2 + \| y - (x - dz_0) \|^2, \end{align}
which is minimal for $y = x - dz_0$.
Since, you *know* that the projection $y_0$ is the *unique* minimizer,
we obtain $y_0 = x - dz_0$. That is $z_0 = (x - y_0) / \|x - y_0\|$.